# Pop to next viewController in ios

Tags: ios, swift, popviewcontroller

I used this code :

`self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)`

By using this it is poping to view controller but tableView is not loading at a time,i need to go back and come again then it is loading.

This code :

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DiscountViewController") as! DiscountViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc , animated: true)
```

By using this code i'm popping to view controller ,also loading `tableView` at a time, but the problem is, that it is going two or three to return back because we are pushing the viewController.

How can solve this by using `popToViewController(vc, animated: true)`  and load tableView at a time?

Initially this code

`self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)`

has worked. Whatever I'm trying also I'm not able to pop view controller and reload() tableView when popViewController is used.

How to solve this?

Comment: It is working.     Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelDautermann its better to write your solution as an answer so that Zaheer will be able to accept it

Comment: okay! done... normally I wouldn't do this, because it's such a simple answer/comment, but if Zaheer accepts, I think he earns some points/badges for accepting an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are popping back to a previously displayed view controller, then you can reload your `tableView` by doing `reloadData` in that `DiscountViewController`'s `viewWillAppear` function.